Previously working URL Session code no longer works in Xcode 15
After dusting off an old project it no longer works in Xcode 15. I have the 'URLSessionDelegate' correctly set and below is a simplified method:
'''
    let user = "user"
    let pass = "pass"
    let token = "123456"
    let url = "https://192.168.17.254:7443/api/auth/login"

    let authUrl = URL(string: url)
    var authRequest = URLRequest(url: authUrl)
    authRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    let authBody = ["username": user, "password": pass, "token": token]
    authRequest.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: authBody, options: .prettyPrinted)
    
    authRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    authRequest.setValue("TOKEN=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
    
    let authSessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let authSession = URLSession(configuration: authSessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    authSession.dataTask(with: authRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            //Never reaches code here, no error no data

    }.resume
        

'''
I also have the delegate for 'didReceive challenge' which I have tried a few versions of from other questions on here ..
'''
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    print("didRecieve URLAuthenticationChallenge")
    
    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust  {
        print("send credential Server Trust")
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        challenge.sender!.use(credential, for: challenge)
        
    }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic{
        print("send credential HTTP Basic")
        let defaultCredentials: URLCredential = URLCredential(user: "username", password: "password", persistence:URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        challenge.sender!.use(defaultCredentials, for: challenge)
        
    }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM{
        print("send credential NTLM")
        
    } else{
        challenge.sender!.performDefaultHandling!(for: challenge)
    }
}

'''
I did have this working previously but now I get API MISUSE errors, and it infers the completion handler wasn't called even though it was, as you can see the print statement in the output. I've also tried various other answers, from here part of which is in the code above as it looked more complete than what I was using.

I am connecting to a local web server that uses HTTPS on port 7443 but doesn't have any certificates etc, I thought about posting a sample project but without the local web server you wouldn't be able to reproduce it. I suspect it some new ATS security in Xcode 15 but I have no idea what it wants me to do to fix it.

This code is incorrect:
    challenge.sender!.use(credential, for: challenge)

It's not up to you to call use() here. It's up to you to call the completion handler (which is what the error is saying).
The code you want here is:
completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)

Similarly for the other legs of your function.
For complete details see Handling an authentication challenge.

Thanks Rob, the handler code above was from an answer to another question on here and looked more complete than what I had. I originally had this  ... completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust)). However using your answer I think I have a way forward as I can at least get in to the code block now. I will read up about the completion handler and ensure the other outcomes are handled correctly.

So that has got me over one hurdle but after the ServerTrust challenge it appears the it is then requesting a Client Cert with NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate. Now the client doesn't use any certs and all the Auth is done via the JSON Body in the POST, however I can't work out how to respond to the Cert Request without the server returning a 401. So I am still unable to authenticate though I am significantly closer than I was. This all works fine in Postman and has previously worked fine in IOS / tvOS.

I would talk to your server team and discuss why they're sending you a client cert request now. For example, if they're modifying behavior based on user agents. You will need to look carefully at exactly what you're sending via Postman. Also the fact that you were misusing the API formerly, but it happened to work in older SDKs (but it was always incorretc), suggests you may also be misusing the API in other places. I would build a small test app, based on the documentation linked above, and make sure you're doing everything by the book.

Thanks, unfortunately I don't have access to the server team, it's a vendors box that I am talking to. I have however discovered that they seem to have moved the port for Auth from 7443 to plain 443, but still respond on 7443 with the Client Cert Request. I'm reverse engineering this, which is why it's all a bit poke and hope. Thanks for the replies I think I have what I need from your first response.
